# Cant update profile picture using Microsoft Graph API and Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, microsoft-graph-api

I need to update the profile picture by uploading it from local and then update it using the MICROSOFT GRAPH API, I tried the below code

```
<input type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png"(change)="uploadImage($event.target.files)">

uploadImage(files) {
    let file = files[0];
    if (file) {
        this.getBase64(file).then(data => {

            const headers = new Headers({
                'content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            });
            const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

            this._http.patch('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value', data, options)
                .subscribe(res => {});
        });
    } 
}

getBase64(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    });
  }
```

I get the following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
    "message": "An internal server error occurred. The operation failed., The value is set to empty\r\nParameter name: smtpAddress",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "2532c086-a844-4d80-87e8-ad96545396c4",
      "date": "2018-03-15T11:38:33"
    }
  }
}
```

It is based on the doc [https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_update](http://this)

How do I update the profile using Microsoft Graph API from my Angular App, how the Binary Data for Image can be obtained. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting an error regarding the `smtpAddress` being "set to empty" is that this user doesn't have an Exchange Online mailbox. You can only upload profile photos to users with a valid Exchange Online mailbox. Users with an on-prem mailbox or Outlook.com are not supported.

From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/profilephoto):

> A profile photo of a user, group or an Outlook contact accessed from Exchange Online. It's binary data not encoded in base-64.

Also, you need to send the raw binary file, *not* a base64 encoded representation of the image.

Comment: Thanks you @Marc. Is there a way that I can know if any user has an Exchange Online Mailbox?

Comment: There are a few ways. You can see which services have been provisioned using Microsoft Graph's `/v1.0/me/provisionedPlans`.

Comment: You are right the services provisioned returns a null array for the user, I would like to know if there a way add the service. I need to update the profile pictures of the users in my AZURE ACTIVE DIRECTORY

Comment: You need to purchase a license/subscription and assign it via the portal.